# Unable to restart embedded Tomcat with Spring boot without restart JVM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I observed an issue when I stop my Spring Application, it did shutdown Tomcat gracefully and close application context. 
There is no more thread related with my Spring Application in the JVM.

However I cannot start my Spring Application after that. I got the following error:

```
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
```

If I restart my JVM, then I can start my Spring Application just fine.
Is this expected behavior of embedded Tomcat and Spring?

I am using embedded-tomcat version 8.5.4 and spring-boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE

```
2017-03-22 00:15:16.393 ERROR ProvisionNodeApplication [N:ProvisioningNode] [TX:] : Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the output? Something earlier on will tell you why it couldn't start

Comment: @AndyWilkinson that is all the stack trace I get. From JConsole I can see ContainerBackgroundProcessor [tomcat] cannot be started. Do you have any similar experience before?